# Why is Spring Boot Get Request give null error?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

Example JSON data:

```
{
  "type1": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type2": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "type4": "polyline"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type3": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            21.011127,
            52.230914
          ],
          [
            21.013166,
            52.229978
          ],
          [
            21.011331,
            52.22911
          ],
          [
            21.00845,
            52.228953
          ],
          [
            21.009062,
            52.230011
          ],
          [
            21.009513,
            52.230287
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type2": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "type4": "polyline"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type3": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            21.022489,
            52.226406
          ],
          [
            21.023004,
            52.228995
          ],
          [
            21.018069,
            52.230007
          ],
          [
            21.018755,
            52.225618
          ],
          [
            21.016202,
            52.22454
          ],
          [
            21.013906,
            52.226735
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type2": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "type4": "polyline"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type3": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            21.013627,
            52.232005
          ],
          [
            21.018165,
            52.231933
          ],
          [
            21.019228,
            52.232537
          ],
          [
            21.019989,
            52.232925
          ],
          [
            21.019109,
            52.233201
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When i do POST request, the data is saved to database and i get response same as the data that i post. Post request:

```
@PostMapping(path="/savegeojson", consumes = {"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public GeoJson saveData(@RequestBody GeoJson geoJson) throws IOException{
        return geoJSONService.save(geoJson);
    }
```

But when i do GET request i get this error:

> java.io.EOFException: null    at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2926)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3433)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:3491)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readUTF(ObjectInputStream.java:1239)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.readNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:837)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDescriptor(ObjectInputStream.java:988)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2034)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2235)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1744)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.(ObjectInputStream.java:2617)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:652)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.readObject(BigDecimal.java:4282)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor41.invoke(Unknown
> Source) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1231)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2434)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2268)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1744)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2168)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:2168)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:514)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:472)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:225)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:670)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.hydrate(ComponentType.java:670)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeGet(ComponentType.java:330)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.readElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:861)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.readFrom(PersistentBag.java:131)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.finishUpRow(CollectionReferenceInitializerImpl.java:76)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.readRow(AbstractRowReader.java:91)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractRows(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:157)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:94)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:105)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:87)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:705)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:2203)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:595)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:264)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:591)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:787)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:1001)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:987)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:362)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1454)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
> ~[hibernate-core-5.6.4.Final.jar:5.6.4.Final]     at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:128)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:155)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:143)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:159)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
> ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
> ~[spring-tx-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:145)
> ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.1.jar:2.6.1]    at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
> ~[spring-aop-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy103.findByOrderByIdDesc(Unknown Source)
> ~[na:na]  at
> com.example.gponbackendvanillajs.controller.GeoJSONController.getByOrderByIdDesc(GeoJSONController.java:41)
> ~[classes/:na]    at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> Method) ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
> ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]    at
> javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:4.0.FR]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
> ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
> ~[spring-web-5.3.15.jar:5.3.15]   at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.56.jar:9.0.56]    at
> java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Get request:

```
 @GetMapping("/getbyorderbyiddesc")
    List<GeoJson> getByOrderByIdDesc(){
        return geoJSONRepository.findByOrderByIdDesc();
    }
```

Repo:

```
@Repository
public interface GeoJSONRepository extends JpaRepository<GeoJson,Long> {

    List<GeoJson> findByOrderByIdDesc();
}
```

Model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
public class GeoJson {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id; 

 @Column(name="feature_collection_type")
    private String type1;
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "feature_group", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "geojson_id"))
    private List<Feature> features = new ArrayList<Feature>();

    public GeoJson() {
    }
}
```

- 

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Feature {
    @Column(name="feature_type")
    private String type2;
    @Embedded
    private Properties properties;
    @Embedded
    private Geometry geometry;
}
```

- 

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Properties {
    @Column(name = "property_type")
    private String type4;
}
```

- 

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Embeddable
public class Geometry {
    @Column(name = "geometry_type")
    private String type3;
    @Type(
            type = "coordinates_array",
            parameters = @org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(
                    name = "sql_array_type",
                    value = "BigDecimal"

            )
    )
    @Column(
            name = "coordinates",
            columnDefinition = "BigDecimal[][]"
    )
    BigDecimal[][] coordinates;
}
```

Additional info: coordinates value persist as BLOB in MySQL database.

Hibernate post (this request works) logging:

```
Hibernate: insert into geo_json (feature_collection_type, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into feature_group (geojson_id, coordinates, type3, type4, feature_type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Hibernate get (this request fails) logging:

```
Hibernate: insert into geo_json (feature_collection_type, id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into feature_group (geojson_id, coordinates, type3, type4, feature_type) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

2022-03-07 08:57:24.539  WARN 18288 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts      : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) : org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@202c4fac<rs=HikariProxyResultSet@1880147977 wrapping Result set representing update count of 3>
2022-03-07 08:57:24.539  WARN 18288 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext   : HHH000160: On CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained [1] entries
2022-03-07 08:57:24.543 ERROR 18288 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize] with root cause
```

Comment: Have you put `getByOrderByIdDesc` method inside `@RestController` or `@Controller`? If latter is the case, you should `@ResponseBody` annotation as well.t

Comment: @SemyonKirekov `getByOrderByIdDesc` method is inside `@RestController`. Still i tried adding `@ResponseBody`  annotation it did not solve the issue.

Comment: Is that the full error log? Could you provide more verbose information?

Comment: @SemyonKirekov I added the full error log and an additional info.

Comment: `findByOrderByIdDesc()` is that the actual method declaration? According to its name, there should be `Order` parameter. Perhaps there is a runtime error because Spring cannot generate correct SQL statement. By the way, there is `CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList` in the log. So, it might be the cause of the problem. Can you turn on SQL logging and add the result query?

Comment: @SemyonKirekov I added Hibernate logging at the bottom. I cannot see if there are wrong things.

Comment: `getByOrderByIdDesc` for this method I don't see any fields named `Order` in your `GeoJson` entity class. How did you get this?

Comment: verify things by running findAll;


i don't think it's an issue with JPQL but with Parsing-Entity specific to BigDecimal

Comment: @user404 `Order` is a Spring Boot feature that automaticly orders items. I also tried to get all data without ordering with `repository.findAll()`, it gives same error.

Comment: @MuhammadAwaisRashid `findAll()` gives same error. Coordinates are saved as BLOB in MySQL

Comment: @TranceAddict, I think `Order` feature needs to declare in this way: `findByFieldNameOrderByFieldNameDesc`.  I can rechek your declaration mactching with this.